# React Navigation: How To Call Specific Function When User touches outside the Nav Drawer to Close it?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Native Navigation to create an App Drawer. I want to call a specific function or set a listener when the user clicks outside the drawer to close it. I went through the docs of react navigation for the same but couldn't find it.
Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: React navigation v3

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this--

```js
  toggleDrawer = () => {
   
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  
   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
        
          <Image
            source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
            style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

Comment: This did not work. For those curious, this code was taken from:
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-navigation-drawer/